# storing Geopoints into Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to store my location into the parse.com database, but i have having an issue doing so. First of all, I can't store anything into the database I believe it is returning null or something so. Not quite sure whats the behavior. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

```
       double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();


        // Get longitude of the current location

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


        ParseObject parkingobject = new ParseObject("Cooking");
        parkingobject.put("username","Alana");
        ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(latLng); //<----- This is where the error is.
        parkingobject.put("Location", point);
```

Comment: Dear Eggz; What is LatLng? Can you provide more information related with this? Actually, why don't you try the ParseGeoPoint object constructor with two parameters (Latitude and Longitude ).

Comment: I did pass latitude and longitude as an argument but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();


        ParseGeoPoint geoPoint = new ParseGeoPoint(latitude , longitude );


        ParseObject parkingobject = new ParseObject("Cooking");
        parkingobject.put("username","Alana");

        parkingobject.put("Location", geoPoint );
```

Try this code.

Comment: This code didn't work. It does not create the username alana with the user geopoint

Comment: Just did but i did it in your post

Comment: You need to read about Parse. Kindly read the documentation, you need to learn about how pointers work.